# SQL Order By A List

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I am trying to write an sql query for Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Here is a quick sample of my query.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT(field1)
FROM     myDatabase
WHERE    field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids')
OR       ....lots of other conditions....
```

I then want to order by those ids in the dynamic list descending and then the rest descending. Something to this effect.

```
ORDER BY field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids') DESC, 
         field1 DESC
```

How am i able to have the ids in the dynamic list first?

Thanks

**EDIT** - Added DISTINCT to query.

**EDIT** - Answer as provided by Shan Plourde.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT(field1),
         CASE 
           WHEN field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids') THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS logicalOrderingColumn
FROM     myDatabase
WHERE    field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids')
OR       ....lots of other conditions....
ORDER BY logicalOrderingColumn DESC, field1 DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this?

```
order by case when change_request_id in ('dynamic list of ids') then 0 else 1 end, 
      change_request_id desc
```

Comment: Now it is showing this error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Comment: You'll have to include that case expression as a column in your select statement. I.e.: select *, case when change_request_id in ('dynamic list of ids') then 0 else 1 end, change_request_id desc as orderinglogiccolumn

Answer (score 2):

You can use case statements in order by:

```
ORDER BY case when field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids') then 1 else 0 end DESC,  field1 DESC
```

Comment: Now it is showing this error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Answer (score 2):

You could use two queries, one with the dynamic ID's and the other with the rest. Then join them together using the `UNION ALL` operator.

Comment: I did think of this but i have never really liked union so i was trying to avoid it. +1 for a correct answer though.

Comment: `UNION` will resort the list to check for duplicates, did you mean `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Yes, I meant UNION ALL - I've changed the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try This as @Heming Says.

```
SELECT   *
FROM     myDatabase
WHERE    field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids')
order by Field1 DESC
UNION ALL
SELECT   *
FROM     myDatabase
WHERE    field1 NOT IN ('dynamic list of ids')
order by Field1 DESC
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to order by the largest number where field 1 is in the dynamic list of id's and then by field1 descending.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids') THEN field1 ELSE 0 END DESC, 
         field1 DESC
```

Comment: Now it is showing this error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a large number to `field1`:

```
ORDER BY case when field1 IN ('dynamic list of ids') then 1000000 + field1 else field1 end DESC
```

You would need to make sure the large number was larger than any of the numbers in `field1`.

Comment: Now it is showing this error "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."

Comment: You might need to wrap the query into a sub-select with the ORDER BY clause as an additional field then sort by that in the top-level query...